# Where can I find a reference of the CG shader language?

Tags: reference, shader, cg

I am new to shaders and I would like to find a list of all (or most/common) functions, variables, availeble to write CG shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/index.html

Comment: the link is dead :(

Comment: New root of the Cg Language documentation can be found at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/index.html. @AarondeWindt was specifically asking for the Standard Library functions, which can be found here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/index_stdlib.html.